# Dynamic Dictionary usage in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dictionary

I am using a Dynamic dictionary in C#. The problem I am facing is the behavior of TryGetMember which I am overriding in the dynamic dictionary class.

Here's the code of dynamic dictionary.

```
class DynamicDictionary<TValue> : DynamicObject
{
    private IDictionary<string, TValue> m_dictionary;

    public DynamicDictionary(IDictionary<string, TValue> a_dictionary)
    {
        m_dictionary = a_dictionary;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder a_binder, out object a_result)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        var key = a_binder.Name;
        if (m_dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            a_result = m_dictionary[key];
            returnValue = true;
        }
        else            
            a_result = null;

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Here, TryGetMember will be called at runtime whenever we refer some key from outside, but it's strange that binder's Name member which always gives the key what we refer from outside, it always resolves the key name written as characters of alphabets.

e.g. if the object of DynamicDictionary made as:

```
Dictionary<string,List<String>> dictionaryOfStringVsListOfStrings; 

//here listOfStrings some strings list already populated with strings
dictionaryOfStringVsListOfStrings.Add("Test", listOfStrings); 
dynamic dynamicDictionary_01 = new 
    DynamicDictionary<List<String>(dictionaryOfStringVsListOfStrings);

string somekey = "Test";

//will be resolve at runtime
List<String> listOfStringsAsValue = dynamicDictionary_01.somekey
```

Now what happens here is "somekey" will become the value of a_binder (i.e a_binder.Name="somekey"). It should be resolved as a_binder.Name = "Test"  and then from the dynamic dictionary it will locate listOfStrings against this key (i.e. actually "Test" but it resolves not the value but actual variable name as key).

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of dynamic typing is to make the member names themselves get resolved from the source code member access.

Dynamic typing is working exactly as it's meant to here - it's not *designed* to retrieve the value of the variable and use that as the member name - it's designed to use the member name you used in your source code (i.e. "somekey").

It sounds like you really don't need dynamic typing at all here - just use `Dictionary<string,List<String>>` as normal:

```
List<String> listOfStringsAsValue = dictionary[somekey];
```

EDIT: It sounds like you actually want to encapsulate a dictionary like this:

```
public class Foo // TODO: Come up with an appropriate name :)
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public List<string> this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> list;
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
            {
                list = new List<string>();
                dictionary[key] = list;
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
foo["first"].Add("value 1");
foo["second"].Add("value 2")
foo["first"].Add("value 1.1");
```

If you want to be able to attempt to fetch a list without creating a new one if it doesn't exist, you could add a method to do that.

It really doesn't sound like you need DynamicObject here.

Comment: might not used then dynamic dictionary correctly but above normal usage of dictionary won't work in my case.
My keys are populating randomly and with out any sequence values of those keys that are actually the strings (those actually will be added in the list of that key) are adding. In dynamic dictionary we just refer key and it gives back values(i.e list of strings) and if I add string inside list , it actually gets added under list of that mentioned and specified key of whom values to be populated dynamically.